# Android Distinct in SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

```
return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {rfrom
}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Below query is correct statement by the way of using with rawquery tag of sqlite. What I want is I want to replace following query statement into above query using existing sqlite's query.  Is there anyway can be complete for that?

```
select distinct col from 
(
    SELECT classa col FROM school 
    union all 
    SELECT classb col FROM school
) a 
order by col
```

Comment: `query` doesn't support subqueries. Why not use [`SQLiteQueryBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html)?

Comment: Its possible using SQLiteQueryBuilder only. Do you want to implement in that way ?

Comment: yap, can you let me know how to use SQLiteQueryBuilder for above sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out as below the use of `SQLiteQueryBuilder` :

> ```
> public void testUnionQuery() {
>     String expected;
>     String[] innerProjection = new String[] {"name", "age", "location"};
>     SQLiteQueryBuilder employeeQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
>     SQLiteQueryBuilder peopleQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
>     employeeQueryBuilder.setTables("employee");
>     peopleQueryBuilder.setTables("people");
>     String employeeSubQuery = employeeQueryBuilder.buildUnionSubQuery(
>             "_id", innerProjection,
>             null, 2, "employee",
>             "age=25",
>             null, null, null);
>     String peopleSubQuery = peopleQueryBuilder.buildUnionSubQuery(
>             "_id", innerProjection,
>             null, 2, "people",
>             "location=LA",
>             null, null, null);
>     expected = "SELECT name, age, location FROM employee WHERE (age=25)";
>     assertEquals(expected, employeeSubQuery);
>     expected = "SELECT name, age, location FROM people WHERE (location=LA)";
>     assertEquals(expected, peopleSubQuery);
>     SQLiteQueryBuilder unionQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
>     unionQueryBuilder.setDistinct(true);
>     String unionQuery = unionQueryBuilder.buildUnionQuery(
>             new String[] { employeeSubQuery, peopleSubQuery }, null, null);
>     expected = "SELECT name, age, location FROM employee WHERE (age=25) " +
>             "UNION SELECT name, age, location FROM people WHERE (location=LA)";
>     assertEquals(expected, unionQuery);
> }
> ```

For more details visit [Link](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-cts/android/database/sqlite/cts/SQLiteQueryBuilderTest.java.htm)